# How to convert query to arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, transpose, flatten

I would like to ask on how to convert this query to an arrayformula:
`=query({unique(filter(A$2:A,B$2:B=B2)),sequence(rows(unique(filter(A$2:A,B$2:B=B2))))},"select Col2 where Col1 = '"&A2&"'")`

I also attached this in a gsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oFbGsP42fMphedY7wtZ7C3focVDJxxkVXHdf6aC3_D4/edit#gid=0

The idea is to count sequence number that will restart to 1 for the same **item** if month is different month (but it wont necessarily to crosscheck with month because thinking to concat to others but is still gonna be based on the unique id here)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&B2:B&"×"&
 VLOOKUP(A2:A, {A2:A, TEXT(ROW(A2:A), "00000")}, 2, ), B2:B}, 
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "offset 1", 0),,9^9)), " "))&"×"&SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A))), "×")), 3, )))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi appreciate this, but do you have any idea that the counter not visible on my end when i implement to my actual sheet?

Comment: @KrengKongkeng hard to tell what went wrong in your actual sheet that I did not had a chance to examine

Comment: Can refer here, column Z-AB https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oFbGsP42fMphedY7wtZ7C3focVDJxxkVXHdf6aC3_D4/edit#gid=1936236958&range=Z1

Comment: @KrengKongkeng your Z column contains spaces... see your sheet.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use an Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). To achieve this, follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Copy this function in the script editor, and save the project (check inline comments):

#### Using date:

```
function myFunction(values) {
  values = values.filter(r => r[0].length); // Remove empty rows
  return values.map((row,i) => { // Loop through rows
    const [item, date] = row;
    const month = date.getMonth();
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const monthRows = values.filter(r => r[1].getMonth() === month && r[1].getFullYear() === year); // Filter month rows
    const itemIndex = [...new Set(monthRows.map(r => r[0]))].indexOf(item); // Check index of this item in current month
    return itemIndex + 1;
  });
}
```

- Now, if you go back to your spreadsheet, you can use this function like any in-built one. You just have to provide the appropriate ranges as function arguments (in this case, `A2:B`):

[image]

#### Using ID number:

```
function myFunction(values) {
  return values.map((row,i) => { // Loop through rows
    const [item, id] = row;
    if (item.length) {
      const idRows = values.filter(r => id === r[1]); // Filter id
      const itemIndex = [...new Set(idRows.map(r => r[0]))].filter(String).indexOf(item); // Check index of this item in current id
      return itemIndex + 1;
    }
  });
}
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Hi, wow this is quite advance. Thank you! But if i want to concat month to others, would it be same method as well? Example to concat 001&month (001 is a group ID for A & B), (002 is a group ID for C), (003 is a group ID for D). Hence the counter will restart to 1 every for every groupid and month

Comment: @KrengKongkeng I'm not sure what you mean here. Was this part of the original question? If that's not the case, I'd suggest you create a new question.

Comment: Yes is the same question. I mean in column B, it is not month anymore, but a group of unique id now. Counter will restart to one for each different id now. Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oFbGsP42fMphedY7wtZ7C3focVDJxxkVXHdf6aC3_D4/edit#gid=1936236958

Comment: @KrengKongkeng I updated my answer with an alternate code that uses ID numbers instead of dates. I hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: @KrengKongkeng Was your issue solved?